# Is it possible to use NAS instead of AWS?

Tags: nas, amazon-web-services, mariadb

As a part of my university project, I aim to create a second classification program for books.

I wonder if I should apply [AWS] for project equipment application, or if I can cover it with [NAS].

When I simplify the work I want to do,
As shown below

1. Save the book database information.
2. After uploading the saved DB information to the server side, it will link with the Android app (client) (it seems that it is necessary to process a DB query and process it).

If proceed through this process [aws], it will go smoothly

but
Is it possible to implement it with [NAS]?

Synology [NAS] supports mariaDB

but

However, I do not know whether it will be a query or an answer through SQL Query using Synology NAS

Thank you!

Comment: You could manage MySQL/MariaDB's by installing phpMyAdmin on the NAS. Do you already have the NAS hardware? Either way, I think AWS would be the easiest and best way to go. Learning AWS is a valuable skill.

Comment: @DrZoo Thank you DrZoo. and i'm sorry, but i'll ask you one more question. If you use AWS, there are many types. What should I use? Thank you very much for your reply! (maybe use AWS  Will Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS) work best?)

Comment: Signing up for AWS gives you access to a lot of available tools. With the free tier you get certain amounts of usage free per month and certain storage limits. All of the limits are well within the range for your project. You can either use RDS for MySQL, MariaDB, etc or you can use DynamoDB which is a NoSQL database. Use whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your NAS can run a database server, a web server, and a language you want to write in then it's possible you can use your NAS.

However, it's probably not a great idea. The NAS is one piece of hardware, and you would have to make sure it's backed up. You might be able to have others access it remotely, but you probably shouldn't have a NAS accessible from the internet as it's a security risk.

AWS gives you 12 months of many services free. Everything is backed up well. However, AWS is a complex enterprise environment, so if you don't do some training / learning first you'll probably find it complex and confusing. I've been using AWS for 5 years and I have qualifications in AWS, I work with it in my day job, some areas I find complex and confusing. But for simple systems you'll probably manage ok. AWS is a great skill to have if you want to work in IT.

I suggest you look at AWS Lambda (serverless compute), write your code in any supported language and so long as traffic is low your bill will be low to zero.

For the database suggest you use an auto scaling DynamoDB (NoSQL database). If you need the relational features of a database then use RDS to provide MySQL.

You can also use an EC2 instance. A t2.micro is free for a year, which is 10% of a core and 1GB of RAM. You can do a LOT with that - I use an instance half the size to serve five low volume production websites.